# Derive data provided the abrrieviation from array in javascript. (Highly loaded Array )

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

My array size is >5000. Please help me with an efficient code in javascript which can deal with the above situation (title) as I am at a novice level in JavaScript. This is for a company task purpose. I am currently working on schools and colleges in India

The following api link will provide School names in India (JSON format). 
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=List_of_schools_in_India&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  var intjsresult=[ "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme",
      "Nitte International School",
      "National Institute of Technology",
      "Nitte Meenakshi Institute of Technology",
      "BMS college of Engineering",
      "Rastriya Vidyalaya College of Engineering",
      "Nitte School of Management",
      "Massachusetts Institute of Technology"
    ];
  
  function hello() {
    
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: intjsresult
    });
  }
  $(hello); 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Consider the following Illustration:

- The school / University name is Indian Institute of Technology
  The above should pop if I provide IIT as an Input.
- Stanford University. Input testcase : Stanford, S U
- Massachusetts Institute of Technology . Input MIT, Massachusetts, Massa

Any help would be greatly obliged

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and achieved so far?

Comment: you should share your code, show your effort and then if you are stuck anywhere, we all would like to help you, but if you just ask us to do stuff for you, you can get harsh response as well. Take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide necessary details. And Welcome to SO! :-)

Comment: The above works for Massachusetts, Massa but fails for MIT

Comment: @Rajesh : U can assume a larger data set which I can  perform an ajax request and get the data. For time being please consider the array in the code as my data set.

Comment: Have you copied code from [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)? When I said show your effort, it means your code. I'm sorry but I'm voting question to close.

Comment: @Rajesh : Thanks but I quite figured it out

Comment: @Rajesh : Please do not tell like that. I expected you to help you not start finding the website from where I copied. I copied beacuse I needed it but anyways you can see my implemented solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey This is the solution That I have presented which works fine with my data set. Here is the regular expression that i am using

```
 for (var i = 0; i < intjsresult.length; i++) {

intjsresult[i]+=" "+intjsresult[i].replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '');

};
function hello() {

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: intjsresult
});
}
```

For the above problem This will create a abbreviation considering the capital letters.

Thanks for your help